# Escribir en un input value que no tiene id o algun tag que lo identifique desde javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

(No tengo claro que titulo poner pero creo que el que esta es entendible)

Buenos días, me han solicitado realizar una extensión de Chrome con un pequeño formulario de identificacion que me inyecta los datos en otro formulario que ya es de web, he logrado insertar en unos input en unos campos que si tenían un id o name para identificarlos desde javascript pero tengo el problema es que uno de esos input que necesito no tiene un id o algo para buscarlo en el DOM(tiene un class pero no he podido porque los otros input tienen el mismo valor), les dejo el codigo de ese input.

No tengo tantos conocimientos en javascript y no se que mas metodos hay.

```html
<input
  type="text" ng-model="visitorFormAdd.identityCode"
  maxlength="128" data-input-type="identitycode"
  data-parsley-required="true"
  hik-tip="Input 1 to 128 characters (digits or letters). "
  ng-blur="visitorFormAdd.searchVisitor()"
  class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-valid-maxlength parsley-error ng-touched"
  data-parsley-maxlength-message="Input 1 to 128 characters (digits or letters). "
  data-parsley-required-message="It cannot be empty or contain spaces only."
  data-parsley-id="6"
  data-parsley-id-message="Input 1 to 128 characters (digits or letters). "
  style=""
>
```

Cordial saludo,

Comment: Por lo que veo es parte de un formulario de AngularJS, que usa ParsleyJS para validarlo... `data-parsely-id` o `ng-model` son dos atributos que deberían tener valores únicos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")[x]
```

Donde x es la posición del input de la página -1.
Esto significa que si es el cuarto input type=text de la web, debes poner el número 3 en lugar de la X.

Mírate los selectores de css porque puedes obtener un elemento y su hijo, por clase, por tag, y muchos etc.

Aquí tienes una buena colección:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono, algo así estaba buscando pero no lo encontraba

Answer (score 1):

Prueba este selector: `"input['data-parsley-id=6']"`.

Si no te vale, busca el elemento padre más próximo que sí puedas identificar de alguna manera, y después buscas dentro de este el `<input>`.